# Backpacking in Egypt and Kenya: Applying for a visa on the road and onward travel requirements

Tags: visas, backpacking, egypt, kenya

I'm intending to travel to different countries soon. As an ASEAN Citizen I am free to travel to any ASEAN country (southeast Asia), after travelling in ASEAN I'll be headed to India where we can get a VOA or ETA. So I want to know if can I get an Egyptian Visa from India and if I can book one way ticket to Egypt from India?

Then I might be backpacking Africa and start in Kenya where I am visa-free. Can I book again one way ticket from Egypt to Kenya without return or onward ticket? (let's say I'll be backpacking Kenya-Tanzania)

Comment: What is your citizenship ? It might not matter in SEA, but might make a difference in Egypt or Kenya

Comment: Blackbird57 I am Filipino

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain an egyptian visa in India from the embassy in New Delhi or consulate in Mumbai. This [website states](http://www.solobackpacker.com/2013/08/04/egypt-visa-information-for-indian-citizens/) that "there is no need to appear personally at the embassy to apply for the Egypt visa. You can also apply with the help of any visa agents".

Regarding one-way ticket; I cannot answer specifically for Filipino's but in my experience of back-backing overland or using one way tickets i have never encountered a problem. As often proof of return or onward travel seems to be a requirement, though [this online agent](https://egypt.visahq.com/) suggests that a travel itinerary should be sufficient absent a return ticket. If you add a cover letter explaining your intentions and proof of your previous travels i doubt you'll have any trouble obtaining a visa.

The lack of return ticket is occasionally questioned by customs but easily answered if you look like a tourist (and not a potential migrant) and your passport is full of visas and stamps from previous countries.

To make sure you could talk to a visa agent online or in India. Better yet contact now the [Egyptian embassy in India](http://www.mfa.gov.eg/english/embassies/egyptian_embassy_india/contactus/pages/default.aspx) with your query: india_emb@mfa.gov.eg.

In the worst case book a flexible ticket from Egypt to Kenya. That should meet Egyptian authorities' onward travel requirement.